# Auto submit form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to automatically submit a form when you have filled in 4 numbers in the input.
I currently have just a basic html form:

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
   <input type="number" maxlength="4">
</form>
```

And now I want that if you reach the maxlength it automatically submits the form, so you do not have to hit enter or submit.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can do this by Jquery. Have you tried anyting?

Comment: I can use the basics of PHP, but have no experience with Jquery. Sorry.

Comment: have you tried anything yet in PHP?

Comment: Not Possible with just PHP.

Comment: Well then look into jQuery, @BramvanDartel, HTML does not support anything like you want, so you'll need to implement this yourself. This feature you want is really easy to implement, so this is the perfect opportunity to get started with jQuery too!

Comment: @HamzaZafeer I figured that out, have done some research and tried, but I am pretty sure you need a script for this.

Comment: Yup, best way to do is jquery. Do some R&D and you will get the solution.

Comment: I disagree that jQuery is the best way to do this. Standard JavaScript and the DOM have the necessary capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - use a key up triggered frunction and using jQuery - also getting the maxlength in the function since it could change in the future. I also aded an alert in there so that you can see the effect in the snippet- just for in SO.

```js
    
    //js (assuming use of jQuery)
    $('[name=sampleInput]').on('keyup',function(){
    var maxlen=$(this).attr('maxlength');
    var len=$(this).val();
    if(len.length == maxlen){alert('form submitted');$('[name=sampleForm]').submit();}
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form name="sampleForm" action="send.php" method="POST">
    <input name="sampleInput" type="number" maxlength="4">
    </form>
```

Comment: Note that the `onkeyup` event does not capture all changes made to the value of an input box. And jQuery really is not needed for this.

Comment: fair point - further logic would be required to pick up the number incrementors or the effect of pasting a value into the box. I agree - jQuery might be overkill, but I do like it and it is fairly common to have it in pages these days. But I wouldn't include it in the page just for this solution - you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way:

1. Add keyup listener to input
2. Check length of value in it

```js
function checkField(input) {
  if(input.value.length == 4) {
    document.forms[0].submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
  <input type="number" onkeyup="checkField(this)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that the `onkeyup` event does not capture all changes made to the value of an input box.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `oninput` attribute:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="4" oninput="if(this.value.length==4) this.form.submit();">
```

This also works if a value of 4 digits is pasted in the input box with the mouse (so no keyboard event will take place).

You can move the code in a `script` tag instead, capturing the `oninput` event:

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
    <input type="number" maxlength="4">
</form>
<script>
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=number]');

    input.oninput = function() {
        if (input.value.length == 4) {
            input.form.submit();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: best to keep your javascript functions seperate from your HTML - seperation of structure and function etc...

Comment: Thanks @gavgrif. I agree, and I have added that as alternative.